# PHP REGISTRATION Assistance

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a php registration Script with a php form validation. The Validation seems to be working fine But it is independent of mysql insert query so whether the form input is correct or not the data will still be sink into the data base.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<title>
Register Page
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<!--header-->
<?php include("include/header.php"); ?>

<!-- end header-->
<!-- nav-->
<?php include("include/nav.php"); ?>

<!-- end nav-->
<!-- left bar-->
<?php include("include/left_bar.php"); ?>
<!-- end left bar-->
<!-- content-->
<div id="content" align="left">
<form method="post" action="check_register.php">
First Name: <br><input type="text" name="fname" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($fname)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please Your Frist Name Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
Last Name: <br><input type="text" name="lname" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($lname)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please Your Last Name Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
User Name: <br><input type="text" name="username" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($username)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please Your User Name Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
Email:<br> <input type="email" name="email" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($email)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please Your Email Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
Password: <br><input type="Password" name="password" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($password)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please a Password Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
Phone: <br><input type="tel" name="phone" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($phone)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please Your Number Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
Gender: <br><input type="text" name="gender" ><br>
<?php if (isset($_POST["submit"])&&(empty($gender)))
{ echo"<center><em><div id='form'>Please Your Gender Is Required<br></div></em></center>";}?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
</form>
</div>
<!-- end content-->
<!-- right bar-->
<?php include("include/right_bar.php"); ?>
<!-- end right bar-->

<!-- footer-->
<?php include("include/footer.php"); ?>
</div>
<!-- end footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

that is my register.php that contain the php form validation.

Here is check_register that contains the mysql query

Someone Please Use master eye and Spot the Problem for me

```
    <?php
$host="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$db_name="login";
$db_table="login";
mysql_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpass")
or die("Could Not Establish Connection");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die(mysql_error());

$fname=$_POST["fname"];
$lname=$_POST["lname"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$gender=$_POST["gender"];
//validation of input in the form fieldS
include("register.php");

$submit=mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(fname,lname,username,email,password,phone,gender)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email','$password','$phone','$gender')") or die("REGISTRATION NOT COMPLETED Thanks");
if($submit==TRUE){
Echo"<div style='background:yellow;'><script>alert('YOU HAVE SUCESSFULLY REGISTERED PLEASE LOGIN WITH YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD');</script></div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$host="localhost";
$dbuser="root";
$dbpass="";
$db_name="login";
$db_table="login";
mysql_connect("$host","$dbuser","$dbpass")
or die("Could Not Establish Connection");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die(mysql_error());

$fname=$_POST["fname"];
$lname=$_POST["lname"];
$username=$_POST["username"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
$gender=$_POST["gender"];
//validation of input in the form fieldS        
include("register.php");
 if (isset($fname) && isset($lname) && isset($username) && isset($email) && isset($password)&& isset($phone) && $isset($gender) ){
$submit=mysql_query("INSERT  INTO users(fname,lname,username,email,password,phone,gender)VALUES('$fname','$lname','$username','$email','$password','$phone','$gender')") or die("REGISTRATION NOT COMPLETED Thanks");
}
if($submit==TRUE){
Echo"<div style='background:yellow;'><script>alert('YOU HAVE SUCESSFULLY REGISTERED PLEASE LOGIN WITH YOUR USERNAME AND PASSWORD');</script></div>";
} 
?>
```

That Is the Answer.

Answer (score 4):

Its because your `action="check_register.php"` .so when you `submit` your form it directly goes to `check_register.php` . without looking for any things inside your form.
So you must validate your form in `check_register.php`. thats all.

Answer (score 1):

in add to @Nabin Kunwar:

first know the difference between client side and server side language.php is a server side language that means it will be executed only in the server.

1.so u cant write php validation in the html file.

now understand wat 'action' in form does.it contains the address where your data inserted into the form i.e query string(name=value pair) will go for processing.it mainly contains the address of a php file or some other server side language file.so if the value exists in the databse or not will be evaluted in the server not in the client side.

2.so if u want to generate any error message dynamically than use ajax which will act as a communication medium between the client and server while the user is filling the form or u can do it via php also  but the error message will only be shown when the user presses the submit button or u can use javascript also if u dont want to put submit button in your form.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing...where is the sanitation?!? You should be using `mysql_real_escape_string()` for *all* variables users can manipulate.

Secondly, javascript-side code won't prevent users from submitting a form. You must also validate a user's input on the server side (by using code like `if (empty($_POST['foo'])) { reject and go back }`). Even if you disabled the submit button until everything is valid, disabling javascript would disable those checks, too.

Comment: Am not using java script wot you z wot am using chk my script vry well

Comment: Okay...what *are* you using? I see PHP. But that validation code will never fire as your actual checks should be on the page you POSTed to, not the form itself. Unless...is this script posting to itself? If it is, you need to use `halt` statements to prevent the script from getting to the rest of the code.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be using mysql_* functions as they are becoming deprecated. Use MySQLI or PDO